# Firedate Notification in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to learn Xcode and swift and I am having trouble with getting my notification to work for a simple alarm clock I am making.  I used date picker and had the notification.firedate = to that.  The notification comes up on the notification window but the alert window does not come up and no sound is playing.

I also asked the user to allow notifications already.  Please give me some help.  Thank you

**AppDelegate**

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:  [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:[ .Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))

    return true
}
```

**ViewController**

```
@IBAction func alarmSet(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alarmPicked = timePick.date
    printTime(timePick.date)
    self.notify(alarmPicked)

}
func notify(date: NSDate){
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let comp = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute], fromDate: date)

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    notification.fireDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(comp)
    notification.alertBody = "Here is the you Alarm you scheduled!"
    notification.alertAction = "Dismiss"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8+, UIApplication requires that you register your notification settings. It will let you schedule them if you don't, but they will never fire.

You register your settings like this:

```
let myNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(myNotificationSettings)
```

Then you can schedule notifications which will actually fire.

See Apple's SDK: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: I did do that I believe in the AppDelegate.swift with this code
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:[ .Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))

Comment: Dur, sorry about that. I completely misread the first part of your question and just dashed off an answer. That is strange. If you're getting this behavior in the iOS Simulator and not on a device, it can help to "Reset Content and Settings".

Comment: I tested it on my personal phone as well and it also does not play the sound or display the alert notification.  It just keeps showing up i the notification window though.

Comment: Poking around online I'm finding a lot people with the same issue in regards to the sound not playing and no obvious answer. Try deleting your app off your device, clean your project in Xcode, delete all derived data, then reinstall.